# form still submits after validation fail JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form   and I trying to validate fields which have same class. required

```
<form id="HotelBooking" method="post" action="#">
<input type="text" class="required"  name="vardas" />
<input type="text" class="required"  name="pav" />
<input type="text" class="required"  name="tel" />
<input type="submit"  name="sb"  value="Tvirtinti" onclick="tikrinti();"/>
</form>
```

JS code works for firs field, it shows error, but form still submits and resets the fields.

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $('#HotelBooking').submit(function () {
  $(".required").each(function(){
            if($(this).val().length == 0)
            {
               alert('Please Enter your value');
               $(this).focus(); 
               return false;
            }
        });
 });   
});
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your `return false;` is returning out of the `.each()` loop, not the `submit` event

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should put the `return false` outside of `each()`:

```
$('#HotelBooking').submit(function () {
    var errors = 0
    $(".required").each(function(){
        if( $.trim($(this).val()).length == 0) { // make sure that there is no extra whitespace
           errors++ 
        }
    });
    if (errors > 0) {
       alert('please Enter your value for ' +errors+ 'remaining fields')
       return false;
    } 
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're returning `false` from the `each()`-function, not the `submit()`-function.

Here's a fix:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#HotelBooking').submit(function () {
        var valid = true;

        $('.required').each(function () {
            if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                alert('Please Enter your value');
                $(this).focus();

                valid = false;
            }
        });

        return valid;
    });   
});
```

Edit: Woops, too late

Comment: this would overwite hasError each time, so if the last field has a value, it will still submit regardless of if the preceding fields don't.  (Though the alerts would still trigger.)

Comment: Hmm, no, because `hasError` is always set to `true` it doesn't matter if it gets overridden by another `true` - or am I missing something? Edit: I changed the `hasError`-name (defaulted to `false`) into `valid` (defaults to `true`). In either case, I don't see how overriding either variable with the same value over and over is going to affect the outcome?

Comment: My original comment no longer applies since you've edited your code. I admit the way it's written it now would accomplish the intended goal. Your first answer hower, only returned true/false based on whether or not the last field wasn't empty. And yes, i've noticed you've edited your answer 3 times. Your not even using the same variables anymore. I thunk it's ver dishonest to realize i'm right, correct your answer, and then refute my comment.

Comment: @BrianVanderbusch - I mentioned the second edit in my comment, simply a variable name change. The first edit, however, was made because of an error (I returned `hasError` which would be `true` if the form had errors and `false` if it was valid instead of the other way around) and all I did was change `return hasError` to `return !hasError` (so that the form would return `false` if it _had_ errors). In neither of the revisions would there be a problem with overwriting `hasError` though. Edit: and the last change from `hasError` into `valid` I made simply because I thought it made more sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $('#submitRegister').click( function(){
         var validation =  $('#connect').vValidator('validate');
         Window.alert("hii");
         });
      </script>
```

Comment: Kindly give explanation to your code. Code only answers are not appreciated.